# Float division returning int - PHP 7

Tags: php, precision

Doing what should be a straight forward calculation in PHP 7. The following never produces a float result. Running `var_dump($C)` returns `int(2)`

```
$A = 0.04;
$B = 0.20;

$C = 3*($A/$B)^2;

echo $C;
```

I don't need the result to be float type, I need the precision.

I've tried setting the precision using `ini_set('precision', n)`. I've tried the code on three environments and getting the same result. Declaring `(float)` is also does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try casting the result to float like this: $C = (float) (3*($A/$B)^2);

Comment: simple:`^` does **not** calculate the power, but a binary XOR. `**` does. see also: **[the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php)**

Answer (score 1):

```
3*($A/$B)^2
```

Means `3 * (A/B) XOR 2` (`^` means `xor`) so bascially the result you are seeing is the result of a bitwise XOR on the result of your division.
If you want to raise the result to the power 2, you should use the `pow()` function. You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php .

Answer (score 1):

`^` does not calculate the power, but XOR (which casts float to int).
to calculate the power, use `pow()` or in PHP5.6+ `**`

```
<?php
$A = 0.04;
$B = 0.20;

$C = 3*($A/$B)**2;

echo $C; //output: 0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) instead.

```
$C = 3 * pow(($A/$B), 2);

var_dump($C);  // float(0.12)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<?php

$A = 0.04;
$B = 0.20;

$C = 3 * pow(($A/$B),2);

echo $C; //output: 0.36
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code also include an explanation of what the code is doing.